# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un dato del primer form al segundo form por post? php

Tags: php

Como puedo mantener un dato que se envia desde un form post, al segundo form que esta donde se envia el primer post

```
<form action="presetarAlojamiento.php" method="post" ></br></br>
    <input name="alojamiento" type="text" placeholder="localizacion"></br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
</form>
```

Al segundo form que esta en presentarAlojamiento.php

```
<form action="pedirDatosCliente.php" method="post">

        <input name="DNI" type="text" placeholder="DNI">

        <!-- Borrar los valores -->
        <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

        <!-- Recoger los datos -->
        <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Lo que quiero es guardar de forma oculta el dato para pasarlo por post en el segundo form

Answer (score 0):

El primer form podría ser GET y eso resuelve el problema porque pasas los datos por URL.

Sabiendo esto, si de igual forma deseas recuper el dato enviado por POST entonces usar `$_POST["campo"]` para recuperar el dato.

Comment: y como podría  enviarlo en el segundo  form ese dato pasado por get?

Comment: El formulario 1 debe ser GET
El formulario 2 debe ser POST

En el formulario 2 es donde debes recuperar el dato... `$_POST["campo"]` o `$_GET["campo"]` dependiendo de que uses.

Comment: así lo puedo pasar a pedirDatosCliente.php ? que es a donde va el segundo form?

Comment: Correcto, haz la prueba y nos comentas, saludos.

Comment: me da el siguiente error Notice: Undefined index: alojamiento in C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas - copia\pedirDatosCliente.php on line 3